# Winforms widget to display a grid of constantly updated numbers?

Tags: winforms

I'd like to create a Winform app (Mono support would be a huge plus) to display a grid of rapidly updating numbers, while not running into redraw problems while scrolling.

From searching around I've found:

[Telerik GridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx)

which seems to be exactly what I want. Is the Telerik path the way to go? Or is the capability available within the standard .NET tool set? If so, which widgets should I be looking at to implement such an application?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All the Grid components from vendors are going to have performance issues if you change the attached values very very quickly. So if you need high performance you really need to create your own. If you are concerned only about flicker and the update does not need to be amazing quick then you will be fine with Telerik or indeed any other vendors Grid component.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider implementing Virtual Mode on the Telerik RadGridView to overcome any performance issues you might encounter.

The demo application included with the controls contains an example of a rapidly updating grid. Although its just a small demo, if you resize the window to be smaller the scrollbar will appear and you can scroll without any redraw issues. You can access the demo under GridView -> Performance -> High Refresh.

Unfortunately, the Telerik WinForms controls aren't compatible with mono.